# Would it be illegal to include a Disney character's name in my business's Name?

Tags: copyright, trademark

For example, "Bambi Publishing" or "Pinocchio Publishing?"

Comment: You can't copyright a word/name. This would be a trademark issue.

Answer (score 4):

Neither "[Bambi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bambi_(character))" nor "[Pinocchio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinocchio)" are original Disney characters and the latter is in the public domain as far as copyright goes.

All of the Disney imagery surrounding the characters *is* Disney property.

Comment: Be very careful with this advise.  Just because Snow White is a public domain story does not mean that all of the elements in Walt Disney's Snow White are public domain.  For example, the specific names of the 7 dwarves are Disney owned... Walt went through some 40 different names to get to the 7 we know... and they do not predate him at all.  Thus, Snow White is public domain, Snow White and/or Seven Dwarves is public domain, but the specific Dwarf Dopey is trademarked to Disney.

Answer (score 1):

Even then, Bambi is a legitimate name that pre-dates the source material of the Bambi book or the Disney film that brought the book to the screen, so as long as your Bambi is not a deer, it could work.  All this said, Disney is quite litigious and will come down on remotely similar works of theirs... and the Disney theme parks often do have restaurants and stores that make use of characters likenesses and often pun off of them, though neither of those two buisnesses are stores that I know of.